# Create Systemd service for private blockchain on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nodeos, ubuntu, bash

I have set up of private blockchain using reference https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/tutorials/bios-boot-sequence. My concern is to write the `systemd` service for these nodes to start and stop the `nodeos` after and before reboot/shutdown. I need to stop the node just before the reboot/shutdown using `stop.sh`. This step is just to avoid the unclean shutdown of nodeos which requires replay. And start `nodeos` using `start.sh` after the server starts. I create the service in `/etc/systemd/system/eos.service` :

```
[Unit]
Description=Start and Stop the eos blockchain
After=network.target shutdown.target reboot.target

[Service]
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/home/user/biosboot/genesis/stop.sh
ExecStart=/home/user/biosboot/genesis/start.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service is active but not working. Please help me with writing the service file. Or any other way to start the `nodeos` using the `start.sh` file after server restart/shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't look like a eosio related question but more related to systemd and how to configure it properly.

if the two shel scripts

- /home/user/biosboot/genesis/stop.sh
- /home/user/biosboot/genesis/start.sh

are working well by themselves then most likely the problem is in how you configure systemd.

Answer (score 0):

Add a few more things like:

```
TimeoutStopSec=10m
LimitSTACK=65536000
LimitNOFILE=64000
```